# Disable only double tap and not pinch on UIWebview?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, pinchzoom

I want to disable only double tap on UIWebView not pinch. I tried following code

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *js = @"var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');"
    "metaTag.name = \"viewport\";"
    "metaTag.content = \"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0\";"
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

But it is disabling pinch also.
Can anyone know how to disable double tap on UIWebView without affecting pinch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to remove double tap gesture or just disable for some condition?

Comment: I want to remove double tap. Even if I can disable it, its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding this line:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

or

inject html in order for this to work I think.

use this in `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">
```